# Alter Column Size in Large SQL Server database causes issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a table with more than 600 million records and a `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column.

I need to change the column size to fixed size but I usually have two options with this large DB:

- Change it using the designer in SSMS and this takes a very long time and perhaps never finishes
- Change it using `Alter Column`, but then the database doesn't work after that, perhaps because we have several indexes

My questions would be: what are possible solutions to achieve the desired results without errors?

Note: I use SQL Server on Azure and this database is in production

Thank you

Clarification: I actually have all the current data within the range of the new length that I want to put

Comment: `but then the database doesn't work after that` please elaborate always  and post any errors as text

Comment: Do you want to pass to fixed-lenght column NCHAR(m) or all you want is to change max possible size to a fixed value but leave the column to be of variavle length size(I mean, pass from nvarchar(max) to nvarchar(m))?

Answer (score 2):

Never did this on Azure, but did it with hundred million rows on SQL Server.

I'll add a new column of the desired size allowing null values of course and creating the desired index(es). 
After that, I'll update in chunks this new column trimming / converting old column values to new one. After all, remove indexes on the old column and removing it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! is there a way to copy from the old column to the new column fast? I already have all data within the required length

Comment: `update table set newCol=oldCol where indexedCol between initChunkValue and endChunkValue` this will prevent transaction log indigestion

Answer (score 2):

> Change it using the designer in SSMS and this takes a very long time
>   and perhaps never finishes

What SSMS will do behind the scenes is

- create a new table with the new data type for your column
- copy all the data from original table to newe table
- rename new table with the old name
- drop old table
- recreate all the indexes on new table

Of course it will take time to copy all of your "more than 600 million records".
Besides, the whole table will locked for the duration of data loading `with (holdlock, tablockx)`

> Change it using Alter Column, but then the database doesn't work after
>   that, perhaps because we have several indexes

That is not true.

If there is any index involved, and it can be only indexes that have that field ad `included` column beacuse of its datatype `nvarchar(max)`, server will give you an error and will do nothing until you drop that index. And in case there is no index affected it just cannot "doesn't work after that, perhaps because we have several indexes".

Please think one more time what you want to achieve changing the type of that column. If you think you'll gain some space doing so it's wrong.

After passing from `nvarchar(max)` to `nchar(max)` (from variable length type to fixed length type) your data will occupy more space than now because you are going to store fixed number of bytes even if the column has `null` or 1-2-3 characters.

And if you just want to change `max` to smth else, for example `8000`, you gain nothing because this is not the real data size but only the maximum size the data can have. And if your strings size is small enough, your `nvarchar(max)` is already stored as `in-row data`, not as `LOB data` as it was with `ntext`

Comment: All 100% correct, already added a plus one. The one point I would bring up is that changing to a fixed length of VARCHAR may not be to remove space, but to prevent someone from putting in LOB data. I'd sure want to stop that from occurring if it's not necessary for the function of the system.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I actually want to transform it to nvarchar(xxx). Doing so before saved us a looooot of space in a different column.